# If in Triangle ABC, $\angle C=60°$, then prove that $\frac{1}{a+c} + \frac{1}{b+c} = \frac{3}{a+b+c}$

Tags: triangles

How to solve this $\frac{1}{a+c} + \frac{1}{b+c} = \frac{3}{a+b+c}$. Given that $\angle C=60°$. Please answer as soon as possible. Tomorrow is my test

Comment: Traditional Comment : What have you tried? We don't generally answer those questions which don't show any attempt from asker's side.

Comment: I took LCM of both and then added it. Then I used cosine rule but nothing worked out.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for writing math on this site, or at the very least parentheses. Right now I can't tell whether you mean $\frac 3a + b+c$ or $\frac3{a+b+c}$.

Comment: use that $$\sin(\alpha)=\frac{a}{2R}$$ etc

Comment: Authur i mean the second one. That is what you have written after or.

Comment: @MuhammadAliZafar Can you specify using brackets and edit accordingly?

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1}{a+c}+\frac{1}{b+c}=\frac{3}{a+b+c}\iff$$
$$(a+b+c)(a+b+2c)=3(a+c)(b+c)\iff$$
$$c^2=a^2+b^2-ab=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(60^o)$$

Comment: it must be if and only if

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, thank you. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

the left side of your equation is given by
$$\left( \sin \left( \alpha \right) +1/2\,\sqrt {3} \right) ^{-1}+
 \left( \sin \left( \pi/3+\alpha \right) +1/2\,\sqrt {3} \right) ^{-1}
$$
and the right side
$$3\, \left( \sin \left( \alpha \right) +\sin \left( \pi/3+\alpha
 \right) +1/2\,\sqrt {3} \right) ^{-1}
$$
and the Difference is
$$4\, \left( \sin \left( \alpha \right)  \right) ^{2}-4\,\sin \left( \pi
/3+\alpha \right) \sin \left( \alpha \right) -3+4\, \left( \sin
 \left( \pi/3+\alpha \right)  \right) ^{2}
$$ simplifying this we obtain
$$4\sin(\alpha)^2-4\sin((1/3)\pi+\alpha)\sin(\alpha)-3+4\sin((1/3)\pi+\alpha)^2$$
simplifying this we get
$$3\, \left( \sin \left( \alpha \right)  \right) ^{2}-3+3\, \left( \cos
 \left( \alpha \right)  \right) ^{2}
$$ and this is Zero.